# Someone please help understand a crash?

Tags: ios, xcode4, crash

An iPhone app is crashing on the device but not on the simulator. So I'm trying to learn how to interpret the crash log. I read lots of forum posts saying that the symbolicated crash log shows a back trace that gives the method and line number of the calls leading to the crash but I don't see anything useful. Maybe I'm not looking at the symbolicated crash log. Here is the beginning of what I see:

```
Incident Identifier: 432A8974-1661-409F-B5A6-970148550A46
CrashReporter Key:   db93147c0a70a5f4c60dc92f826e72d5a74477c8
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,3
Process:         Darken [57959]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/CB27C10F-CD3B-4148-8321-2C251888B27B/Darken.app/Darken
Identifier:      Darken
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-02-25 10:43:47.753 -0500
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.2.10 (8E600)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000008
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32716464 objc_msgSend + 16
1   UIKit                           0x3245e6fe -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _scrollViewAnimationEnded] + 90
2   CoreFoundation                  0x32071bb8 -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:] + 16
3   UIKit                           0x3245e5b8 -[UIAnimator stopAnimation:] + 276
4   UIKit                           0x323efbf2 -[UIAnimator(Static) _advance:] + 214
5   UIKit                           0x323efb0e LCDHeartbeatCallback + 10
6   GraphicsServices                0x35474362 HeartbeatVBLCallback + 86
7   IOMobileFramebuffer             0x34739bf4 IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc + 68
8   IOKit                           0x348e5e64 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 192
9   CoreFoundation                  0x32070be0 __CFMachPortPerform + 204
10  CoreFoundation                  0x320686f8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
11  CoreFoundation                  0x320686bc __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 160
12  CoreFoundation                  0x3205af76 __CFRunLoopRun + 514
13  CoreFoundation                  0x3205ac80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
14  CoreFoundation                  0x3205ab88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
15  GraphicsServices                0x354724a4 GSEventRunModal + 108
16  GraphicsServices                0x35472550 GSEventRun + 56
17  UIKit                           0x323c7d1a -[UIApplication _run] + 406
18  UIKit                           0x323c5884 UIApplicationMain + 664
19  Darken                          0x000029d6 0x1000 + 6614
20  Darken                          0x00002998 0x1000 + 6552
```

... Threads other than 0 listed here

Is anything here useful for finding out which line of my code led to the crash? Darken is the name of the application -- I already knew that. The only method name I recognize is UIApplicationMain but the crash didn't happen when the app was first launched -- I was running it about a minute and doing dozens of functions before the crash.

Comment: Have you looked in the device logs (using the Xcode organizer) to see if any error messages align with the time of this crash?

Comment: In general an EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash would point to mismanagement of memory. If you could post the method or section where this happens we would be able to help you in greater detail. Have you tried to debugg on the device to narrow the area down?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try and set NSZombieEnabled to YES in your project and let it crash with your device running in debug. It should stop at the line of code causing your crash. Your error looks like it is an EXC_BAD_ACCESS which usually means you were trying to access some deallocated memory.

Comment: I believe Zombie only works on the simulater, not on the device. Please let me know if this is wrong. As I said in the original posting the crash only happens on the device.

Comment: There's a good video on this site on how to do it:markj.net/iphone-memory-debug-nszombie. It's a bit old, but it should help you find the object that is causing your crash.

Answer (score 0):

1. You won't get a line number from a crash dump (unless you compiled your app with -g and run in GDB, but I doubt it since you don't seem to know what these are at all).
2. You ARE looking at the symbolicated crash dump: you DO have the names of the functions in the call stack. The crash occurs in the last called (topmost) function, which is objc_msgSend. That means you're not properly balancing your alloc/retain/copy methods with autorelease/release, and the messenger function tries to access already freed/corrupted/nonexistent memory, hence the crash (EXC_BAD_ACCESS is similar to a segfault, in fact you'll get one of these when you make such a mistake).

So my advice is, triple check your code for method calls modifying the reference count.

Comment: Your're right I'm not compiling with -g. I did already think that I must have screwed up something about memory management. I've looked at the code over and over again, and cleaned up some things (mainly so it's more readable and understandable) but I couldn't find anything wrong. I was hoping the crash dump would help but I guess it doesn't.

Comment: @bneely: Yes I looked at the log. It shows nothing about this crash.

Comment: @Osiris: I don't know what method or section was involved. That's what I was hoping to learn from the crash report. It happens during the transition from one scene to another (a cocos2d app). It's probably something in the scene that's ending but it has over 500 lines of code and I haven't narrowed the crash down to any one part of it.